# How to manage multiple net clients in Node.js

Tags: node.js, server, client

For my home automation system I'd like to create a NodeJS service that can connect to several servers using net.connect().

I have no idea how to manage that projet, for the moment I'm able to connect to one server (send & receive data), that part is working well.

Each client will have an id and name as properties.

I think I need an array of net clients but I can't find a good tutorial to get that working.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get things working.

First declare something to store clients into and the connect method :

```
var nodes = [];

var node;
node = new events.EventEmitter(); // Maybe we can use something else ?

node.connect = function (id, name, host, port) {
    var node = net.connect({host:host, port:port});
    node.id = id;
    node.name = name;
    node.
    on('connect', function () {
        // we are connected
        node.is_connected = true;
    }).
    on('close', function () {
        // we are closed
        node.is_connected = false;
        node.destroy();
    }).
    on('error', function (err) {
        // there is an error
    }).
    on('data', function (data) {
        // we have data
    });
    // add thos new node to storage
    nodes.push(node);
}
```

Add a new node :

```
node.connect(id, name, host, port);
```

And to remove one, maybe we can do this in a better way, maybe getting by Id (?) :

```
for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].id == id) {
        nodes[i].destroy();
        nodes.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

This is actually working well for my projetc, feel free to discuss this solution, thank you for helping.